# swift xcode stack view option is not shown

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistackview

I am using swift on xcode `Version 6.4 (6E35b)` and I am trying to add my views to a stack view.

When I select my views and choose `editor -> embed in`, I don't have the `Stack View` option.

Also at the button right of the canvas, I can't see the `Stack View` button, as 
you see in this screenshot.

[image]

How can I find it please?
Many thanks for the efforts.

Comment: StackView is new to Xcode 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Xcode 7 and use the latest SDK (iOS 9). (I'm assuming you wish to use the new UIStackView controller, not the exploded view / layering tool).

If you take the Xcode 7 beta you can run them in the same machine side-by-side (since the name is Xcode-beta.app, as I recall).  In fact, you can do this with the release versions as well - just name them appropriately.  Just be sure to change the version at the command line if you're doing things there as well: see [xcode select](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html)

Comment: I have just updated it, and it automatically installed the version i stated in the question. Showed I now install a new xcode (the latest one) and remove the current one?

Comment: If you take the Xcode 7 beta you can run them in the same machine side-by-side (since the name is Xcode-beta.app, as I recall).

Comment: BTW You can also rename the old Xcode "Xcode-6.4.app" if you still need it; that way the updates to the Xcode 7 stream won't keep overwriting it.